# Using Gradient Descent on Linear Regression Yields an Incorrect Bias

Tags: python, machine-learning

I've got a toy example set up of a linear regression model with one input variable and one output variable. The problem that I'm encountering is that the output for the bias is far off from the generated data. If I manually set the bias then it will produce a weight and bias which is close enough to the original.

I've written two pieces of code `gen_data` which generates data and `GradientDescent` which performs that gradient descent algorithm to find the weight and bias.

```
def gen_data(num_points=50, slope=1, bias=10, x_max=50):
    f = lambda z: slope * z + bias
    x = np.zeros(shape=(num_points, 1))
    y = np.zeros(shape=(num_points, 1))

    for i in range(num_points):
        x_temp = np.random.uniform()*x_max
        x[i] = x_temp
        y[i] = f(x_temp) + np.random.normal(scale=3.0)

    return (x, y)

# \mathbb{R}^1 with no regularization
def gradientDescent2(x, y, learning_rate=0.0001, epochs=100):
    theta = np.random.rand()
    bias = np.random.rand()

    for i in range(0, epochs):
        loss = (theta * x + bias) - y
        cost = np.mean(loss**2) / 2
        # print('Iteration {} | Cost: {}'.format(i, cost))

        grad_b = np.mean(loss)
        grad_t = np.mean(loss*x)

        # updates
        bias -= learning_rate * grad_b
        theta -= learning_rate * grad_t

    return (theta, bias)
```

Answer (score -2):

1. If you want to use batch update, don't set your batch_size equals to your simple size. (I also believe that batch_update is not very suitable for this case.)

2.Your gradient calculation and parameter update are incorrect, the gradient should be:

```
grad_b =  1
grad_t =  x
```

For the parameter update, you should always trying to minimize the `loss`, so it should be

```
if loss>0:
  bias -= learning_rate * grad_b
  theta -= learning_rate * grad_t
elif loss< 0:
  bias += learning_rate * grad_b
  theta += learning_rate * grad_t
```

After all, below is the modified code works well.
    import numpy as np
    import sys

```
def gen_data(num_points=500, slope=1, bias=10, x_max=50):
    f = lambda z: slope * z + bias
    x = np.zeros(shape=(num_points))
    y = np.zeros(shape=(num_points))

    for i in range(num_points):
        x_temp = np.random.uniform()*x_max
        x[i] = x_temp
        y[i] = f(x_temp) #+ np.random.normal(scale=3.0)
        #print('x:',x[i],'        y:',y[i])

    return (x, y)

def gradientDescent2(x, y, learning_rate=0.001, epochs=100):
    theta = np.random.rand()
    bias = np.random.rand()

    for i in range(0, epochs):
      for j in range(len(x)):
        loss = (theta * x[j] + bias) - y[j]
        cost = np.mean(loss**2) / 2
        # print('Iteration {} | Cost: {}'.format(i, cost))

        grad_b = 1
        grad_t = x[j]

        if loss>0:
            bias -= learning_rate * grad_b
            theta -= learning_rate * grad_t
        elif loss< 0:
            bias += learning_rate * grad_b
            theta += learning_rate * grad_t

    return (theta, bias)

def main():
    x,y =gen_data()
    ta,bias = gradientDescent2(x,y)
    print('theta:',ta)
    print('bias:',bias)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(int(main() or 0))
```

Comment: grad_t = \frac{\partial Cost}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{n} loss \times \frac{\partial loss}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{n} \times loss \times x \neq \theta. How did you compute `grad_t = theta`?

Comment: @Lukasz Obviously, the gradient was wrong,  But simply mark my answer as useless is not cool. The second part of my answer about loss is meaningful. Also, I will update my answer.

Comment: By the way, if you want to communicate with others, please make your comment readable at first.

Comment: ok, could somebody tell me why my answer is not useful? Thanks at first.